# AngularJS : Why is my $scope not shared with a child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created two directives, one of them is used within the other and it has been created just for the matter of seperation of concerns.

```
<div class="docinputContainer">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <easy-table></easy-table>
</div>
```

I have **omitted the `scope` property** on both of them, therefore i would have thought that i could bind a `keydown` eventon my parent directive, which then could call a $scope method from  the child directive:

```
  // parent 
  element.bind('keydown',function(e){
    $scope.save();          
  });

 // easyTable
 $scope.save = function(){
   // ...
 }
```

However, this method is unknown in my parent directives $scope.

Now i have some questions:

- Why is this? Shouldn't both directives share a scope?
- What would be the best solution to this?

I know i could do one of the following:

- Broadcast an event
- Use a shared service to trigger an event
- Concatenate both directives

I would prefer to share the scope, though. Any help is appreciated

## Solution

I bypassed my issue by binding the element to a scope property on the parent directive, then  binding the keydown event in `easyTable` itself, instead of the parent one.

Comment: I see one directive `easy-table` which is the other one, and where is it declared?

Comment: @Chandermani, the markup containing `easy-table` is the parent directives template.

Comment: Use chrome extension Batrang, and see what scopes are getting created,  which would give you some idea https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Comment: Thank you very much. I found a solution to my problem in the meanwhile, which i'll add to my original question